# didAddAnnotationViews is being called more than once

Tags: ios, mapkit

Sometimes, the following delegates method is being called two times even though I add a new location on the map, does anyone know ?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    //Here
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:[[self.mapView annotations]objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You should put a break point at this point and see what annotations are being added to map view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `-didAddAnnotationViews:` is called when the *views* are added to the map, not the *annotations*. That is, if they go offscreen and get set to `nil`, they could reappear again when the annotation bounding box intersects the screen bounds.